# Get Current Date using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the current date so I can use it at the ending of this link. My code is almost correct but can't figure out what is going wrong.

- **Correct Format Example:**
  **http://zumdb-prod.itg.com/zum/AppServlet?action=aotool&jspURL=clusterTools/toolset.jsp&fegoaltype=RAW&eedbListName=ZUM_CMP_DNS_CMP_Clean&facility=DMOS5-CLUSTER&monthDate=01/09/2022

My results are almost correct but the code returns with the following date 01/0/2022 instead of 01/09/2022

Can someone help me figure out this small bug?

```
<script>
    const getDate = () => {
        let newDate = new Date();
        let year = newDate.getFullYear();
        let month = newDate.getMonth() + 1;
        let d = newDate.getDay();
        return month + '/' + d + '/' + year;
    }



    document.getElementById('Ao').src =
        'http://zumdb-prod.itg.com/zum/AppServlet?action=aotool&jspURL=clusterTools/toolset.jsp&fegoaltype=RAW&eedbListName=ZUM_CMP_DNS_CMP_Clean&facility=DMOS5-CLUSTER&monthDate='
        .concat(getDate());

    document.getElementById('MTD').src =
        'http://zumdb-prod.itg.com/zum/AppServlet?action=aotoolFe&jspURL=clusterTools/toolsetFe.jsp&fegoaltype=RAW&eedbListName=ZUM_DIFF_TEL_IPD_HTO&facility=DMOS5-CLUSTER&monthDate='
        .concat(getDate());
</script>
```

Comment: _"The getMonth() method returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year)."_ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Comment: Consider using [Intl DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using [`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) and not [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay). The latter returns the zero-based day of the week (starting Sunday). You want to get the date of the month.

In order to ensure you get double digits for the month and day, you need to convert those numbers to string first, and then use [`String.prototype.padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart).

```js
const getDate = () => {
  const newDate = new Date();
  const year = newDate.getFullYear();
  const month = newDate.getMonth() + 1;
  const d = newDate.getDate();
  
  return `${month.toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${d.toString().padStart(2, '0')}/${year}`;
}

console.log(getDate());
```

Comment: The month probably needs to be zero prefixed.

Answer (score 3):

Here are alternative methods for native date formatting using `toLocaleString()`

m/d/yyyy

```js
const getDate = () => {
  const date = new Date();
  return date.toLocaleString().split(",")[0];
}

console.log(getDate());
```

mm/dd/yyyy

```js
const getDate = () => {
  const date = new Date();
  return date.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit',
    year: 'numeric'
  });
}

console.log(getDate());
```